# Question about Minimal polynomial and diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ $\in$ $M_n$($\mathbb{C}$) such that $A^k=I$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ . Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Ok, I am trying to prove this way:

If $k=1$, is trivial.

If $k>1$

$A^k = I \iff A^k- I = 0 \iff A^{k-1}- I= (A-I)(I + A + \cdots+ A^{k-1})=0.$

I know that the polynomial $p(x)= x^{k-1}+ \cdots + x^2 + 1 = \displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(x-u_j)$  , $u_j$ is root of unity, $u_j \neq 1 
 \hspace{0.8cm} \forall j \in$ {$1,...,n-1$}.

Let $q(x) = p(x)(x-1)$ we knows that $q(A)=0$ and the minimal polynomial must divide q(x). Since q(x) have only simple roots them the minimal have too so we can conclude that A is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes. A square matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial is square-free.

Comment: Furthermore, a polynomial can be confirmed to be squarefree by taking its formal derivative ( actual derivative if the field is the reals or complexes) and confirming $\gcd(f,f') = 1,$ which in turn is equivalent to the existence of constants $a,b$ such that $af + b f' = 1$ is the constant polynomial $1.$

Comment: Alternatively, you can just check that a Jordan block (of size $>1$) with eigenvalue one can not satisfy your condition $A^k=1$.